# wpf treeviewitem mouse double click

Tags: wpf

i have problems identifying the name of the selected TreeViewItem; i have the follow structure in a treeview:

```
 + Module 1 (name k1)
   - Sub Module 1 (name s1)
 + Module 2 (name k2)
   - Sub Module 2 (name s2)
 + Module 3 Name (k3)
   - Sub Module 3 (name s3)
   - Sub Module 4 (name s4)
```

Me xaml is this:

```
<TreeView x:Name="treview_Menu">
   <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
         <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="OnItemMouseDoubleClick" />
      </Style>
   </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

In code i have this:

```
Private Sub OnItemMouseDoubleClick(sender As Object, args As MouseButtonEventArgs)
   MsgBox(sender.name)
End Sub
```

in the above code always returns the name of the top node, for example, if i double click on sub_module 3 o sub_module 4 always returns the name of Module_3, same happens with sub_module 1 and sub_module 2 ... as I can fix this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue I believe is that `ItemContainerStyle` only applies to the first level of nodes (this I believe is due to the way `TreeView` inherits from `ItemsControl` and `ItemContainerStyle` is inherited from there - where is just applies to the basic `Items` of the `ItemsControl`. Anyway, I'm going off on one...)

You can fix it by instead of assigning the style to `ItemContainerStyle`, just move it to `Resources`, like so:

```
<TreeView.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TreeViewItem}}">
        <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="OnItemMouseDoubleClick"/>
    </Style>
</TreeView.Resources>
```

### Depending on what you want, this might not work as you intend...

Because this adds a trigger to *every* TreeViewItem - and, unfortunately, they nest like so:

```
        <TreeViewItem Header="Module 1">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Sub Module 1"/>
        </TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Module 2">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Sub Module 1"/>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Sub Module 2"/>
        </TreeViewItem>
```

So, depending on what you're actually going to use the code for, it might be a problem that the event fires on *both* the outer and inner module.

The usual way of dealing with this in a `ClickEvent` is to set the `args.Handled` to be `True` in the code, which stops the event 'bubbling' up to the higher levels. But unfortunately this doesn't work on `MouseDoubleClick` events, due to the way they're triggered. (Nice one Microsoft... xD)

A possible answer instead is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6326181/3940783

Basically, we dispense with the `MouseDoubleClick` event, and instead use the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event (which Microsoft uses to trigger the `MouseDoubleClick` event apparently). Anyway, we can get it to fire once like so:

(Please excuse the C#, I tried to answer this from a wpf perspective, but I don't know the equivalent VB code)

```
OnItemPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)   {
    if (e.ClickCount == 2) {
        e.Handled = true;
        var treeViewItem = sender as TreeViewItem;
        MessageBox.Show(treeViewItem.Header.ToString());
    }
}
```

HOWEVER, because a Preview event tunnels down, it unfortunately fires once on the containing item, not the contained item, so we're back to square 1. We could do some looking into the `args.OriginalSource` here but we're basically getting to the stage where a different solution is advisable:

### Separate Alternative

A separate alternative is to just add an event listener to the whole `TreeView` on its double click event, which then simply finds in which `TreeViewItem` its `OriginalSource` is located. (If you want to handle it and stop it propogating / causing other effects, you will need to instead hook onto the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event as above instead).

To do so, you can take the `MouseButtonEventArgs args` and consider `args.OriginalSource` (this is the element top-most on the visual tree that you clicked on) and then you have a few cases: either it's not inside any `TreeViewItem` at all, or it is itself the `TreeViewItem` you require, or the third possibility is that the OriginalSource is an element somewhere inside the `TreeViewItem` you require (this is the most likely case - from testing, you usually click on a `TextBlock` contained within a `TreeViewItem`), in which case you can recursively find parents till you hit the first parent of type `TreeViewItem`. (You can do this using the `VisualTreeHelper` `GetParent` method.)

Basically, the above algorithm can be summed up as just recursively check the current item to see if it's of type `TreeViewItem` or `TreeView` else you make the current item its parent and recurse... If you end on `TreeViewItem`, you have the required item, else if you clicked outside an item, you will end up on `TreeView`.

PS: As I can't write VB, I think explaining the above algorithm's probably better than attempting to write it - but I hope the above explanations will still be useful to you :)

Comment: Hello, thankz for help, works, but because the style of my control is altered (style elements treeview loses) ?

Comment: Don't quite get what you mean? (eg (style elements treeview loses) ?).
If you post your style above and your desired effect I might be able to help :)

Comment: I'm currently using MahApps.Metro, here I have a picture without the event for the click and have another photo with the style altered product for the click event: Photo 1 (http://i.imgur.com/pedXtEI.jpg) and Photo 2 (http://i.imgur.com/hvwP7uV.jpg).

Comment: Ahh okay, sorry! The issue is we're inadvertently overriding your custom style locally, but we want to build on it instead.

So try changing the line defining the style to: `<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TreeViewItem}}">` and let me know how that goes.

Comment: Works ¡¡¡ ... thankz for all =D .. i will put a candle to my holy for you = D

Comment: It's really unbelievable that MS made this popular need so difficult.