# How can I make a textbox listening to a Keypress-Event and an InputBinding together

Tags: c#, wpf, events, textbox, command

I created a login-site in my program in WPF where you enter your credentials and then press Enter or the button below. The button has a command (for View Model Binding) and a Click-Event (I got an AutoResetEvent in Code Behind that shakes the Textbox if the login wasn't successful within a second).

Now I tried the same with the Textbox: Command and Event. So this is my Textbox at the moment:

```
<TextBox Margin="0,0,0,10" Text="{Binding Username}" KeyDown="MainWindow_KeyDown">
                <TextBox.InputBindings>
                    <KeyBinding
                            Key="Enter"
                            Command="{Binding KeyPressCommand}" />
                </TextBox.InputBindings>
            </TextBox>
```

And this is my button:

```
<Button Command="{Binding ConnectCommand}" Content="Connect" Background="#E9712F" Margin="0,10,0,0" FontFamily="Arial" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" Cursor="Hand" Click="Button_Click"/>
```

The button works, it triggers the event and sends the command. But the Textbox completely ignores the Event and just sends the Command to the View Model.

Is there a way to trigger both, event and command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `KeyDown` event Use `PreviewKeyDown`

**UPDATED**

The `KeyDown` event is not raised for navigational keys that would normally be handled by WPF, but the `PreviewKeyDown` event also support those keys.

Maybe helpful: [What are WPF Preview Events?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1460286/11219312)

Comment: But why? What's the difference?