# How to block space in passwordbox in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, passwordbox

I’m using a PasswordBox control in wpf.

I want to block space in the control, but i can’t find the way.
I tried to use a KeyDown event but the event isn’t working.

What is the best way to block space in the PasswordBox?

Comment: "[...] but it isn't working" isn't and will never be a technical description of a problem.What isn't working? What is your code? Please share an [mcve] with us so we can understand your problem and help you

Comment: Try using `PreviewKeyDown` event of `PasswordBox` it worked for me while "KeyDown" didn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For WPF you should using `PreviewKeyDown` Based on [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown?view=net-5.0) occurs before the `KeyDown` event When a key is pressed while focus is on this control.

**XAML:**

```
<PasswordBox x:name="txtPasscode" PreviewKeyDown="txtPasscode_PreviewKeyDown"/>
```

**and in behind :**

```
private void txtPasscode_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Space && txtPasscode.IsFocused == true)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
```

Also in C# native try this :

```
 private void txtPasscode_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == ' ') e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the upvote. According to the docs you've linked, `PreviewKeyDown` "Occurs before the KeyDown event when a key is pressed **while focus is on this control.**". So you don't actually need to check `IsFocused`.

Comment: @HosseinEbrahimi For avoid any ```KeyDown``` events , should using IsFocused. Based on me exprience.

Answer (score 1):

The `KeyDown` event you're handling actually fires after the character added to the passwordbox. You can block it by handling [PreviewKeyDown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown?view=net-5.0) this way(`KeyDown` [won't fire anymore](https://wpf.2000things.com/2012/06/26/588-if-you-handle-previewkeydown-event-keydown-wont-fire/#:%7E:text=The%20PreviewKeyDown%20and%20KeyDown%20events,originated%2C%20the%20KeyDown%20event%20fires.) if user pressed space):

```
private void passwordbox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Space)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

If you need to block an event you're going to use the event beginning with "Preview"(read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460170/what-are-wpf-preview-events)).